# Remove mysqli_connect() (HY000/2002) Warning and send error via JSON Object

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

This is My PHP code.

```
<?php
     $objRes= new \stdClass();
   if(mysqli_connect_errno($con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb"))){
    $objRes->response="ConOrDbFailure";
    $myjson=json_encode($objRes);
    echo $myjson; 
      die();
   }
        ?>
```

Here is my XAMPP status. **I have intentionally stopped MYSQL service**. For testing purposes.

[image]

Here is my output in [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) if the `Mysql` is off. It shows no warning or error if `mysql` is on.

Now my requirement is to remove the warning, while mysql is off. Because I need to parse the `JSON object` in `Android`.

[image]

Comment: use `http://localhost/carbookingapp/signup.php` instead of `192.168.0.108`

Comment: @Bilal Ahmed As it is being connected remotely via postman. so it can't be localhost. It is also mentioned that if mysql is running then there will be no error.

Comment: What about using  bool mysqli_ping ( mysqli $link  ) http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.ping.php. You can check if the connection exist